# Python-Train multiple files in one epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, pickle

I have a very large data images file that I divided it into smaller files and store them as pickles. Now, I need to use them to train a model for multiple epochs (10, 50, or 100)?
I, first, read them before the training part,

```
pickle_in1 = open(path + "TrainPairs1.pickle", "rb")
trainPixel1 = pickle.load(pickle_in1)
trainPixel1 = np.asarray(trainPixel1)
tr_pairs1 = trainPixel1.reshape(trainPixel1.shape[0],trainPixel1.shape[1],71,71,1)

pickle_in2 = open(path + "TrainPairs2.pickle", "rb")
trainPixel2 = pickle.load(pickle_in2)
trainPixel2 = np.asarray(trainPixel2)
tr_pairs2 = trainPixel2.reshape(trainPixel2.shape[0],trainPixel2.shape[1],71,71,1)

pickle_in3 = open(path + "TrainPairs3.pickle", "rb")
trainPixel3 = pickle.load(pickle_in3)
trainPixel3 = np.asarray(trainPixel3)
tr_pairs3 = trainPixel3.reshape(trainPixel3.shape[0],trainPixel3.shape[1],71,71,1)

# train labels:
pickle_lb1 = open(path + "TrainLabels1.pickle", "rb")
tr_y1 = pickle.load(pickle_lb1)
tr_y1 = np.array(tr_y1)

# train labels:
pickle_lb2 = open(path + "TrainLabels2.pickle", "rb")
tr_y2 = pickle.load(pickle_lb2)
tr_y2 = np.array(tr_y2)

# train labels:
pickle_lb3 = open(path + "TrainLabels3.pickle", "rb")
tr_y3 = pickle.load(pickle_lb3)
tr_y3 = np.array(tr_y3)
```

Now I need to train the model for 50 epochs,

```
for epoch in range(50):

# Load weights:
   isExist = os.path.exists(path + "Saved_Weights") 
#print(isExist)
   if isExist == True:
      print("Loading weights...")
      model.load_weights(path + "Saved_Weights/weights.ckpt")
else:
    print("No weights yet...")
    
    # train data:
    #train_pairs.append(f"tr_pairs{i}")

    # train labels:
    #train_y.append(f"tr_y{i}")

  history = model.fit([tr_pairs1[:, 0], tr_pairs1[:, 1]], tr_y1,
    batch_size=128,
    epochs=epoch+1,
    initial_epoch = epoch,
    shuffle=True,
    validation_data=([te_pairs[:, 0], te_pairs[:, 1]], te_y))
 training_loss += history.history['loss']
 test_loss += history.history['val_loss']


base_network.save(path + "my_model")
model.save_weights(path + "Saved_Weights/weights.ckpt")
print("Saving weights...")
```

From the code above, I am only able to run 1 pickle file, but I need to train all of them (the three pickle files need to be fitted in every epoch). What would be the efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

- change the batch size ( 16 -> increase it gradually (32, 64 , 128)
- use context managers, every time you load

```py
with open(path + "TrainPairs1.pickle", "rb") as pickle_in1 :
   trainPixel1 = pickle.load(pickle_in1)
```

- if it still doesn't work , try to change the size of images before loading as np array

Comment: The question is about fitting multiple files per epoch. there are 3 (tr_pairs). How would  I change tr_pairs to tr_pairs1, tr_pairs2, and tr_pairs3 for each epoch?